# Как помочь предложению стать читабельным?

Tags: пунктуация

> Люди приходили для участия в совместных трапезах – вечерях любви и
>   единения, или, как их ещё называли, агапэ. В античности, где любовь
>   имела несколько ипостасей, под агапэ понимали самую высокую и
>   бескорыстную – любовь к ближнему, и считалось, что радости этих
>   вечерей есть предчувствие радости вечной. **В этом таинстве
>   символически объединялись и живые и мёртвые, так с течением времени
>   агапэ была обращена в современный ритуал причастия.** Храм христианина
>   рождался, обретал черты реальности в евхаристическом собрании...

Если убрать ***так*** после ***и живые и мёртвые***, я не искажу авторскую задумку?

Предложите, пожалуйста, какой-нито знак вместо запятой.

Comment: А там предлог в не пропущен?: "что радости этих вечерей есть предчувствие радости вечной".  Или всё-таки  "в радости"

Comment: А "и живые и мёртвые" - разве фразеологизм? Ни жив ни мёртв -фразеологизм, а такого вроде нет, здесь просто однородные члены с повтором союза, по-моему, нужна запятая

Comment: Насчёт предлога - это автору виднее. А про запятуху сказано так: ***не ставится, если третьего не дано***! *То же при парных сочетаниях слов, когда третьего не дано: и муж и жена, и земля и небо.* http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=73

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мысль выражена туманно, не видно процесса превращения (акта обращения) в современный ритуал причастия.

Например:

**Затем начали считать, что этом таинстве символически объединются и живые и мёртвые, — так с течением времени агапэ была обращена в современный ритуал причастия.**

А если вообще убрать *так*, то потеряется ощущение процесса. Дескать, была обращена, а как — не указано.

Comment: Стукну за туманную мысль. Очень даже прозрачная! Лучше было бы: *В этом таинстве символически объединялись и живые и мёртвые... Так с течением времени агапэ была обращена в современный ритуал причастия.*. Это обобщение всему абзацу про агапэ.

Comment: Если объединялись с самого начала, в анточном агапэ, то причем тут *так с течением времени*? А если стали объединяться с течением времени — то скажите об этом ясно и не напускайте туман. Да туман!

Comment: О сердитый М_Г!  *С течением времени*, через агапэ, "храм христианина рождался, обретал черты реальности в евхаристическом собрании: «Ибо, где двое или трое собраны во имя Мое, там Я посреди них».

Answer (score 1):

**В этом таинстве символически объединялись и живые и мёртвые – так с течением времени агапэ была обращена в современный ритуал причастия.**

Перед указательным местоимением  ***так*** в БСП желательно поставить тире.

**ИЗМЕНЕНИЕ**

Да, тогда тире не на месте. Может быть, такой вариант подойдет:

Люди приходили для участия в совместных трапезах – вечерях любви и единения, или, как их ещё называли, агапэ. В античности, где любовь имела несколько ипостасей, под агапэ понимали самую высокую и бескорыстную – любовь к ближнему. **Считалось, что радости этих вечерей есть предчувствие радости вечной, поэтому в таинстве символически объединялись и живые и мёртвые.  Так с течением времени агапэ была обращена в современный ритуал причастия.** Храм христианина рождался, обретал черты реальности в евхаристическом собрании...

Comment: Если я Ваше тире перенесу в свой ответ — будет ли это нарушением авторских прав? :)

Comment: Пожалуйста,  в нашей творческой мастерской всё общее.

Comment: Жасминка, никак нельзя тире! Не помню точно, как я вчера вышла из положения; кажись, после "мёртвых" поставила отточие, а "так" изобразила с прописной. Суть в том, что весь этот абзац - о *рождении христианского храма*, через агапэ. Весь пассаж - про агапэ, а от неё - к евхаристическому собранию: *«Ибо, где двое или трое собраны во имя Мое, там Я посреди них»*.